# weird errors with pylint and git.exc

Tags: pylint, gitpython

Given the following python code:

```
import git

try:
    raise git.exc.GitCommandError("dummy", "foo")
except git.exc.GitCommandError as exc:
    print(exc)
```

pylint complains

```
************* Module test
[...irrelevant errors removed...]
test.py:4:7: E1101: Instance of 'GitError' has no 'GitCommandError' member (no-member)
test.py:4:7: E1101: Instance of 'Exception' has no 'GitCommandError' member (no-member)
test.py:5:7: E1101: Instance of 'Exception' has no 'GitCommandError' member (no-member)
test.py:5:7: E1101: Instance of 'GitError' has no 'GitCommandError' member (no-member)

---------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at -36.00/10 (previous run: 4.00/10, -40.00)
```

The code works fine, I do not understand the errors. git.exc is not an exception, but a module:

```
> python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import git
>>> git.exc
<module 'git.exc' from '/tmp/tmp.ULCyvtUQWx/testenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/GitPython-2.1.11-py3.5.egg/git/exc.py'>
```

pylint version is 2.3.1. I'm wondering whether this is just a bug in pylint or whether I'm missing something...

**Update:** Using git.GitCommandError instead of git.exc.GitCommandError doesn't produce the same error for some reason. Even though the latter is the original name of the class.

Answer (score 3):

Try: `from git.exc import GitCommandError` instead of just `import git`.

Comment: Which is basically the same fix that I did (i.e using git.GitCommandError) just in the opposite direction. In the end it just seems to be a bug/limitation in pylint that it can't see that the code works. But making the import of git.exc explicit is probably a good idea either way.

Answer (score 1):

this is due to the `git.exc.*` subpackages being exposed on the top-level `git.*` package. See [`git/__init__.py`](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/411635f/git/__init__.py), in particular line 38 where we can find the following:

```py
from git.exc import *
```